# how to add line number to QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm trying to code a simple c++ IDE based on Qt. Like any language IDE, a line number is very useful in the code editor.

I'm using `QTreeView` for the editor and I'd like to add this line number feature in. Looks like `QTreeView::header()` only returns the Horizontal header to me. How can I **get the vertical header** to set the line number in `QAbstractItemModel::headerData()`?

Comment: Why would you be using `QTreeView` for the editor control? Shouldn't that be a `QTextEdit`?

Comment: `QTreeView` doesn't have a vertical header.

Comment: I'm creating a "new language", which is like C++ but much simpler. Since its grammar is simple enough, I'd like people to write code in a treeview widget.

Comment: QTreeView doesn't have a vertical header? That's bad news.

Comment: Here you can use similar approach -- [SO: Adding Vertical headers to a `QTreeView`][1].

Good luck!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967210/adding-vertical-headers-to-a-qtreeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a vertical header. If you're set on using `QTreeView` in this way, you will need to treat the line numbers as column data associated with each item in your data model (presumably derived from `QAbstractItemModel`). Each time a line is inserted, you will have to walk through your data model and update the line number associated with each data item that comes after the inserted line.

Before going too far down this path, I would download the source code for QtCreator and look at how its file editor widget is built.

Comment: thank you Penn! that works for me.Just need to tune the column color to make it more like a vertical header.